# importando dados extensão ".data"

Tags: python, pandas

Meu código Python está carregando um dataset da internet, mas o mesmo não está reconhece o número de colunar dos dados.

Código Python:

```
import pandas as pd

##Importando dados
data = pd.read_table('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data', header=1)

print(len(data.columns)) 
2
```

Preciso definir mais algum parâmentro?
Tentei `delimiter = "\t"` mas obteve o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O separador dos 8 primeiros campos do arquivo é o caracter espaço e não TAB (`\t`).

Para ler o arquivo corretamente, acrescente o parâmetro `delim_whitespace=True` e altere o parâmetro `header` para 0 (pois o arquivo não possui cabeçalho).

Exemplo:

```
data = pd.read_table('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data', delim_whitespace=True, header=0)

data
Out[15]:
     18.0  8  307.0  130.0   3504.  12.0  70  1          chevrolet chevelle malibu
0    15.0  8  350.0  165.0  3693.0  11.5  70  1                  buick skylark 320
1    18.0  8  318.0  150.0  3436.0  11.0  70  1                 plymouth satellite
2    16.0  8  304.0  150.0  3433.0  12.0  70  1                      amc rebel sst
3    17.0  8  302.0  140.0  3449.0  10.5  70  1                        ford torino
4    15.0  8  429.0  198.0  4341.0  10.0  70  1                   ford galaxie 500
5    14.0  8  454.0  220.0  4354.0   9.0  70  1                   chevrolet impala
...

print(len(data.columns))
9
```

Comment: Excelente! Muito obrigado.